# How to programmatically update Networking Access Restriction on Azure Web App

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure webapp and normally if I want to block an IP address, I go to Azure dashboard panel and under networking>Configure Access Restrictions, I add a rule to do so. This picture shows which menu item I mean:

[image]

However, I would like to do this programmatically. I see that the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions#manage-access-restriction-rules-programmatically) shows how you can do this through Powershell.

I have also managed to find the [API documentation for WebApp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps). But I can't find the last piece of the puzzle which is the API that does what I need.

Can someone please tell me if it is possible and which API I should use? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions#manage-access-restriction-rules-programmatically): Use an Azure REST API PUT operation on the app configuration in Azure Resource Manager. The location for this information in Azure Resource Manager is:

```
management.azure.com/subscriptions/subscription ID/resourceGroups/resource groups/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/web app name/config/web?api-version=2020-06-01
```

Then I searched the Azure Rest API and found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/createorupdateconfiguration):

```
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{name}/config/web?api-version=2019-08-01
```

We could update the field [properties.ipSecurityRestrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/createorupdateconfiguration#ipsecurityrestriction) to update the value of Access Restrictions.

In addition, you could also check this blog: [Bulk add IP Access Restrictions to Azure App Service using Az PowerShell](https://swimburger.net/blog/azure/bulk-add-ip-access-restrictions-to-azure-app-service-using-az-powershell)

Comment: Thank you so much for this. That is exactly what I was after. I found the API but couldn't find the properties doco that now you shared. I have a follow up question. Will the webapp restart after updating the properties.ipsSecurityRestrictions?

Answer (score 0):

There does not appear to be a one-to-one match between powershell commands and api.

The closest I could find is:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/putprivateaccessvnet

This allows you to define which vnet has access to your web app. By controlling access to your vnet, you can control access to your app.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I might be able to use this but this is not the API to add rules unfortunately. I am also thinking that there must be an end point for it. If you can do it through powershell, then Azure must be providing an end point to allow powershell add rules with priority, name, description, etc.. to the access page.